# $ manage.py runserver /system/bin/sh: manage.py: not found

Tags: python, django, qpython

I would be away from a computer (pc) for a while but I have a project on my neck so I got qpython.

I installed Django successfully but after creating a project (successfully with all the files...) but when I

```
$ manage.py runserver
/system/bin/sh: manage.py: not found
```

Though Django-admin runserver doesn't work... It tells something about

```
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE Or settings.configure()
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: what is your system?

Comment: Linux, Android 6.0, LG Phoenix 2

Answer (score 2):

two way for correct run, by parameters of python

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

or use current dir

```
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I've done all that - when I add 'python' before manage:

u0_a137@m1v:/storage/emulated/0/name
$ python manage.py runserver
error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.

2, ./manage.py which I thought would work didn't:
$ ./manage.py runserver
/system/bin/sh: ./manage.py: can't execute: Permission denied